# Defining normal distribution in canonical quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, fourier-transform, second-quantization

For simplicity, let us suppose quantized scalar field

$$\hat{\phi}=\int{\frac{d^3p}{\left(2\pi\right)^32E_\vec{p}}\left(a_\vec{p}e^{-ipx}+b^\dagger_\vec{p}e^{ipx}\right)}$$

How does one add a particle to the state, that is given by some general distribution, for example normal one?

$$\phi=Ae^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}.$$

P.S. what I see as a problem is that a particle always considered to have one value of momenta, so it is always equally distributed over space

Comment: You might be confusing Fock space (occupation number state, where one adds particles) and one-particle wave functions of the first quantization.